# How to add Cygwin package to installed git-scm?

Tags: git, cygwin

I have git installed with Cygwin on a Windows 7 machine (used [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/)). How do I add Cygwin packages (like openssh-server) to the existing install?

I can't find instructions anywhere, or an option to modify the existing Cygwin install.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git from http://git-scm.com/ (the version I would recommend using on Windows) does not use Cygwin, so there is no such environment to modify.

The Windows builds are provided by the [msysGit](https://msysgit.github.io/) project, whose [FAQ has this to say](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/What-is-this-MSys-thing-in-MSysGit):

> ### What is this MSys thing in MSysGit
>
> MSys is an environment for Windows offering a Unix-type shell and a Perl interpreter. Because many parts of Git are still not builtins programmed in C, but instead shell and Perl scripts, Git for Windows needs such an environment.
>
> Therefore we ship Git for Windows with a very minimal version of MSys.
>
> MSys is also required to build Git, as we re-use the same Unix-type setup upstream Git uses. We ship a more complete MSys environment, including GCC, as build environment (which is therefore nick-named ''msysGit'').
>
> We compile Git as a pure [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) program, though, i.e. a program without any link-dependencies on anything but standard Windows libraries. So unless you need to use any parts of Git that are still implemented only as shell or Perl scripts, you can get away with running plain git.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the info. By that comment I'm assuming I can install Cygwin without affecting the existing MSys install. I'll try it out.

Comment: @victorbrca, yes, you should be able to.